# CSS table naming

Tags: css, html-table

Is there any way I can rename this CSS code to only affect a certain table instead of all the tables on my site?

```
 th {
font: bold 11px "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #4f6b72;
border-right: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
border-bottom: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
letter-spacing: 2px;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-align: left;
padding: 6px 6px 6px 12px;
 }

 th.nobg {
border-top: 0;
border-left: 0;
background: #C1DAD7;
 }

 td {
border-right: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
border-bottom: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
background: #fff;
padding: 6px 6px 6px 12px;
color: #4f6b72;
 }

 td.alt {
background: #F5FAFA;
color: #797268;
 }

 th.spec {
border-left: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
border-top: 0;
background: #fff;
font: bold 10px "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 }

 th.specalt {
border-left: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
border-top: 0;
background: #f5fafa;
font: bold 10px "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #797268;
 }
```

and the HTML code:

```
 <table id="mytable" cellspacing="0"> 
   <tr> 
   <th width="202" class="nobg" scope="col">Configurations</th> 
   <th width="250"></th> 
 </tr> 
 <tr> 
   <th scope="row" class="spec">Model</th> 
   <td>M9454LL/A</td> 
 </tr> 
 <tr> 
   <th scope="row" class="specalt">G5 Processor</th> 
   <td class="alt">Dual 1.8GHz PowerPC G5</td> 
 </tr> 
 <tr> 
   <th scope="row" class="spec">Frontside bus</th> 
   <td>900MHz per processor</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
   <th scope="row" class="specalt">Level2 Cache</th> 
   <td class="alt">512K per processor</td> 
</tr> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specifically target the table that you showed the html code for, do this:

```
#mytable th {
font: bold 11px "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #4f6b72;
border-right: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
border-bottom: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
letter-spacing: 2px;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-align: left;
padding: 6px 6px 6px 12px;
 }

#mytable th.nobg {
border-top: 0;
border-left: 0;
background: #C1DAD7;
 }

#mytable  td {
border-right: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
border-bottom: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
background: #fff;
padding: 6px 6px 6px 12px;
color: #4f6b72;
 }

#mytable  td.alt {
background: #F5FAFA;
color: #797268;
 }

#mytable  th.spec {
border-left: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
border-top: 0;
background: #fff;
font: bold 10px "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 }

#mytable th.specalt {
border-left: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
border-top: 0;
background: #f5fafa;
font: bold 10px "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #797268;
 }
```

You wouldn't need the full table#mytable.

Answer (score 3):

You can change your CSS selectors to match only a specific table ID, so for instance...

```
#mytable th {
font: bold 11px "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #4f6b72;
border-right: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
border-bottom: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
letter-spacing: 2px;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-align: left;
padding: 6px 6px 6px 12px;
 }

#mytable th.nobg {
border-top: 0;
border-left: 0;
background: #C1DAD7;
 }

#mytable td {
border-right: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
border-bottom: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
background: #fff;
padding: 6px 6px 6px 12px;
color: #4f6b72;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put `table#mytable` in front of every css selector.

```
table#mytable th{
}
table#mytable th.nobg{
}
table#mytable td{
}
table#mytable td.alt{
}
table#mytable th.spec{
}
table#mytable th.specalt{
}
```

Or just `#mytable`.

```
#mytable th{
}
#mytable th.nobg{
}
#mytable td{
}
#mytable td.alt{
}
#mytable th.spec{
}
#mytable th.specalt{
}
```

Comment: The first version doesn't do anything special since IDs are unique.

Comment: It adds a little weight to the whole css selecting thing. :) http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#cascading-order

Comment: Then why not make sure to provide the more specific ones? E.g. `html > body table#mytable  tr > th` ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can prefix every rule with your table id (#mytable) so you'll have something like

```
#mytable th {
font: bold 11px "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #4f6b72;
border-right: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
border-bottom: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
letter-spacing: 2px;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-align: left;
padding: 6px 6px 6px 12px;
 }

 #mytable th.nobg {
border-top: 0;
border-left: 0;
background: #C1DAD7;
 }

 #mytable td {
border-right: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
border-bottom: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
background: #fff;
padding: 6px 6px 6px 12px;
color: #4f6b72;
 }

 #mytable td.alt {
background: #F5FAFA;
color: #797268;
 }

 #mytable th.spec {
border-left: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
border-top: 0;
background: #fff;
font: bold 10px "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 }

 #mytable th.specalt {
border-left: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
border-top: 0;
background: #f5fafa;
font: bold 10px "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #797268;
 }
```